# Run python in Mac terminal. Sometimes it runs well, sometimes it gets stuck and no response

Tags: python, debugging

I'm self-learning Python by following Coursera python for everybody course. I wrote several files yesterday and all of them confront with a common issue while running in Mac terminal, sometimes it runs fast and well but most of the times it gets stuck and has no response for a long time. For example, one of the files gets stuck and my terminal looks like following:

```
TopSecrets@StevendeMBP: ~/Desktop/Coursera/Python for everybody/Course3 > python3 CA13_JSON.py 
Retrieving http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_55310.json
(it got stuck here...)
```

I asked my friend and was told this issue may result from my terminal buffer limit. I googled some thread and changed the limit, but it doesn't help.

My 6 code and one function package called in code (bs4, for BeautifulSoup) are zipped together. The google drive link is:
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uh7_hTRsmuBv_dikFmhIzBb5Oy8eP5wf/view?usp=sharing)

You can run any one of them several times in terminal, see if they got stuck.

Thank you very much!

Comment: please don't post images of text. type it out and use the formatting tools to format as code or block text.

Comment: Please include a copy of CA13_JSON.py or a link to it with your question.

Comment: And why do you think it's related to the Mac terminal ? Does it run fine in another environment (IDE or like) ?

Comment: Just upload a google drive link. Thanks

Comment: I'm using Atom to write the code. And I'm not familiar with IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me. On MacOS, you should perhaps remove or comment the second line (`os.system("clear all")`) that supposed to clear the terminal screen but doen't change the result. The output is:

```
Retrieving http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_55310.json
User count: 2
total sum is  2351
```

If it still doen't work, I suspect it hangs fetching http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_55310.json with your internet connection that seems unstable.

Comment: Hi Glenfant, thank you very much for your help. I just delete the second line, but It seems not to solve the issue. I should probably try it on other PCs later.

Comment: Did you try to fetch that URL with wget or curl ? I suspect that URL hangs from your network. For mine, it's OK.